# How does this surge protection work?

Tags: microcontroller, signal, protection, detection

This circuit signals an MCU via OU lead. I am not interested in the MCU side. I just show the concept.

My question is very simple: How does the surge protection(actually ı meant detection) part work?

By the way, I have basic knowledge of TVS, MOVs, opto-couplers and RC theory (phase etc.)

[image: schematic]

Comment: which section is the surge protection?

Comment: @jsotola, I agree with you and #VTNCaGNtdDVNalUy that the OP's circuit is just a surge detection circuit, with alarm messaging and data logging etc. In other words, ***no protection parts there***. I know very little about surge protection, except basic things such as lighting rod, earthing stub, circuit breakers etc.

Answer (score 2):

I can read and write Chinese.  So let me translate.

The schematic has 4 blocks on the top row, another at the bottom.

The labels are:

Top: ***Sensor***, Voltage limiter, Surge processing circuit, Optocoupler

Bottom: Remote input, alarm circuit, core MCU, long distance transmission circuit.

I think it is the top left block's ***L01 inductor that picks up the surge*** and kick starts everything.

Comment: Try to avoid using phrases like "I think". That is for philosophers, not engineers. Do not imply that you are not certain about part of your answer. Better to say "I am certain" and be wrong, then to write "I think", and have members wonder about your answer. Just a heads up...

Comment: @VTNCaGNtdDVNalUy, Thank you for your advice. Actually I am certain that L01  inductor is the sensor that picks up the surge, that is what I can contribute, beside e Chinese translation. Actually I am a bit confused of what the OP is asking, because he says he knows all the stuff including TVS, MOV etc.  So I think what he needs is the name of the blocks that explain/confirm the general operation. I read the schematic again and found all the stuff are just basic electronics. The OP's question is a bit vague. If he asks about the details of any block, I am certain to answer. Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a surge detection device, so to work dependably it must have its own surge protection. It starts with an MOV at the L01 inductor input, which is sensitive to surges and outputs a voltage based on surge current through a nearby conductor. But it only works with a minimum surge. The MOV is to clamp over-voltage before it is fed into the bridge rectifier.

Regardless of surge polarity the bridge rectifier gives it a single peak value. This peak is clamped by TVS01, then current limited by R011 before sending the current to an opto-coupler, which prevents violent surges from directly entering the MPU. The MPU can be used to count surges over a certain current level. With flash storage it can show surge activity per hour/day/week/month/year. This can be tied in to storms or heavy motor activity.

To the bottom right another TVS device protects a serial port, either USB or RS-485. This design has adequate surge protection, not including external SPD.

Comment: Is L01 a transformator coil or just independent coil that senses main ? and what is the purpose of the C010 and D014. By the way thanks for your good reply.

Comment: L01 could be a local CT, or one the size of a small resistor. No way to tell without photos. C01 is to filter out Rf noise beyond 1 MHZ, which normally is not surge but contactor noise. D014 is to prevent negative voltages from affecting the opto-coupler. Not sure it is really needed, but was not my call.

Answer (score 2):

> *How does the surge protection part work?*

It may not work at all - surge suppression is a "numbers game". This means that any surge suppression method is reliant on assuming that the incoming surge energy is below a certain value. If the surge energy is above that which the circuit was designed to withstand then the circuit fails to suppress and may sometimes become a hazard in its own right. This is because devices can go short circuit and blow fuses.

For instance, the MOV in the top left circuit box will go short circuit if over-exposed to surge energy - so it needs a fuse else it might short-out a bona fide AC supply. The selection of a fuse is a numbers game; surge suppression is a numbers game so, where are the surge limit numbers?

If the surge is undefined then any circuit is meaningless. If the devices are not linked with data sheets then analysis is also meaningless. A surge suppression circuit is only as good as the specification it was designed to.

Comment: Having been in the SPD industry for a few decades I agree with your synopsis. There are "Wrath-of-God" surges that blow even industrial suppressors to bits. A positive lightning strike close by or a direct hit will leave the service entrance panel a mess.

Comment: Worse than the "wrath of god" is the "envy of god" - then the gremlins are dispatched big time.